# Problems reading subset of HDF5 dataset in Fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran90, hdf5, intel-fortran

I have a very large HDF5 file and wish to read a small subset of it using FORTRAN. My attempts thus far have failed and I'm confused by the documentation.
Any pointers you could give to a FORTRAN newbie (but reasonable C/python coder) would be much appreciated.

In particular I'm having real difficulty understanding what the dataspace and memory space are, in my code they don't seem to be doing what I expect based upon the documentation I've read. That's probably my own idiocy though!

This is what I am trying:

```
integer, allocatable                    :: tmpdata(:,:) ! Array to contain data subset
integer(HID_T)                          :: fid          ! HDF5 File ID
integer(HID_T)                          :: did          ! Dataset ID
integer                                 :: error        ! Error variable
integer(HSIZE_T), dimension(1:2)        :: count        ! Number of px to read (x,y)
integer(HSIZE_T), dimension(1:2)        :: offset       ! Starting point for read (x,y)
integer(HID_T)                          :: dataspace        ! Dataspace
integer(HID_T)                          :: memspace     ! Memoryspace

offset=(/58000,22000/)          ! Set offset in 2d dataset
count=(/1200,1200/)             ! Set # pixels to read (1200x1200 slab)
allocate(tmpdata(1200,1200))        ! Allocate space to store this slab

call h5open_f(error)
call h5fopen_f ("myfile.h5", H5F_ACC_RDWR_F, fid, error)        ! Open HDF5 file

call h5dopen_f(fid, "mydataset", did, error)        ! Open dataset
call h5dget_space_f(did, dataspace, error)          ! Retrieve dataspace 


call h5screate_simple_f(2, count, memspace, error)      !Create memspace, rank=2,size=1200x1200 
call h5sselect_hyperslab_f(dataspace, H5S_SELECT_SET_F, offset, count, error)       ! Select slab in the data 
call h5dread_f(did, H5T_NATIVE_INTEGER, tmpdata, dimsm, error,memspace,dataspace)       ! Read the data from the HDF5 file into the tmpdata array

! Close everything
-snip-
```

Everything goes OK up until the h5dread_f call. Then I get a segfault. If I set tmpdata equal to the size of the actual dataset in the HDF5 file then it works, but this isn't a good solution as for some files the dataset will be too large to store in memory.
Any ideas? Hopefully I'm simply doing something dumb. In case it's important I'm compiling with ifort and HDF5-1.8.15 Patch 1 on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: How is `dimsm` declared?

Comment: is `dimsm`  an `integer(HSIZE_T) :: dimsm(2)` with the values `[1200, 1200]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description and omission of the variable `dimsm`, I'm going to guess you have that variable set to the full dimensions of the variable you are reading.  Those dimensions should instead be the dimensions of the hyperslab you set up, which are also the dimensions of the variable you are holding the results of the read in `tmpdata`.  You can use the same array that you are using to create the hyperslab, `count` in the call to read.

Change:

```
call h5dread_f(did, H5T_NATIVE_INTEGER, tmpdata, dimsm, error,memspace,dataspace)
```

to

```
call h5dread_f(did, H5T_NATIVE_INTEGER, tmpdata, count, error,memspace,dataspace)
```

And your read should work.

What was happening (if my assumption is correct) is that `dimsm` contains the values of the full dataset dimensions (or anything greater than 1200 in both dimensions) and so the call to read the data attempts to read data outside the bounds of the dataspace (which was set to a 1200x1200 view at your given offsets) and if that isn't the segfault, then it would be trying to put the larger than 1200x1200 read into the 1200x1200 variable `tmpdata`.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying - I fixed this a while back and forgot that I'd posted on here. For anyone else who stumbles on this topic - this answer is correct. It will solve the problem I discuss.

Comment: @os1 could you let me know the version of hdf5 you were using?
I can see in hdf5-1.10.x source code that this subroutine is commented out.

asking as i am getting following error in my application  -   
" There is no matching specific subroutine for this generic subroutine call.   [H5DREAD_F] "

Comment: @PuneetS.Chauhan what version are you looking at?  `h5dread_f`is an interface to a few module procedures and is defined in the file `fortran/src/H5DFF.F90` in HDF5 1.10 and probably in a similar location in HDF5 1.8.  Do you have `use hdf5` in your module to pickup all of the hdf5 code?

Comment: @puneets.chauhan also, that error indicates `h5dread_f` is being found, but you are calling it with arguments that don't match any possible subroutines that the generic interface lists. Doie check the number and type of your arguments.

Comment: @casey, i have raised this issue at hdf5 forum with more details. Please have a look - https://forum.hdfgroup.org/t/h5dread-f-symbol-missing-in-hdf5-fortran-libraries/4410.

Comment: @PuneetS.Chauhan the subroutine is commented out because it is now implemented as a generic interface and there are 3 or 4 subroutines that actually get called when you call h5dread_f, depending on the arguments you are calling it with, and your error is that none of them match your arguments. If you post a new Q with a MCVE, ping me and I'll take a look at it for you.